# Solana Keygen Pubkey Prompt Won't Let Me Type

Tags: keypair, seed, solana-keygen, pubkey, beginner

[image]

[image]

Following the Solana documentation [here](https://docs.solanalabs.com/cli/intro#keypair-conventions), when I follow the instructions for some reason it doesn't let me type in the seed phrase to connect a wallet to the command interface. It brings up the cursor but doesn't let me type anything.

Am I doing this entirely wrong? I can use the hardware wallet but I wanted to do it this way. Maybe I'm thinking about it entirely wrong.

Comment: It appears this is just finding the wallet address of a wallet to use for the keypair - these instructions don't spell it out. will resolve it or whatever if I figure this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still typing, just the command doesn't reveal what you are typing. This is typically used with sensitive information like passwords or in this case a seed phrase. Try just typing the seed phrase and hitting enter, it should work fine.

Comment: Solid thanks! It doesn't tell you this so I had no idea.